# Probability Mutually exclusive and complementary

Tags: probability

Three streets meet at an intersection. One of them is under construction.  A street is chosen at random. Show that the probability of choosing the street under construction and the street not under construction is same as choosing either the street under construction or the street not under construction.

My understanding:
P(choosing street under construction) = 1/3
P(choosing street NOT under construction) = 2/3
The two events are complementary, hence, probability of choosing = 1/3 + 2/3 =1.

They are also mutually exclusive, hence, again, 1/3 + 2/3=1.

Is the understanding correct.  Thanks.

Comment: That's correct. They are trying to emphasize that the probability doesn't change based on the order of which you choose one of the streets.

Answer (score 0):

If **a** street is choosen, it can only be one or the other; but not both (that is: they are mutually exclusive).  And there is nothing else to choose (that is: they are complementary).

$\begin{align}P(C) & =\tfrac 1 3  & \text{street under construction}
\\ P(\neg C) & =\tfrac 2 3 & \text{street NOT under construction}
\\ P(C \cap \neg C) & =0 & \text{street under construction AND NOT under construction}
\\ P(C\cup \neg C) & = 1 & \text{street under construction OR NOT under construction}
\end{align}$

Comment: Street under construction AND NOT under construction, are they not complementary and hence add up to 1 (1/3 + 2/3) ?

Comment: @Ramesh How can a street be both under construction and not under construction?

Comment: Because they *are* complementary events, *therefore* their intersection is a null event.